# Rewrite Two Domain with different Ports on single IIS server

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, dns, ports

we have two domain

www.site1.com
www.site2.com

in IIS both site binding at

site1:8081 directory C:/websites/site1/

site2:8082 directory C:/websites/site2/

we want to rewrite rules as

http://www.site1.com to site1:8081

and

http://www.site2.com to site2:8082

How?

Comment: You can't rewrite one website to a different website, you would have to redirect. Why do you need the different port numbers anyway? It would be easier if you can point www.site1.com to c:\websites\site1 and www.site2.com to c:\websites\site2. Then you don't need any rewrite/redirect rules.

Comment: We are using IIS and we cannot bind two websites on port 80.

Comment: Of course you can, it's called host headers. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx